# Buildfire Local Widget Failure

Tags: buildfire

I'm working on my buildfire app locally. Last night I closed my laptop without any errors. Today, I hit the refresh button and got this error:

[image]

Not sure what's wrong. My other apps that I haven't touched in a while are also not working / getting the same error screen. Also, the admin panels still work fine, just not the widget itself. No errors when I go to app.buildfire.com. I even tried pulling the latest sdk but still getting an error.

Nothing in the widget is responsive when I click on it except the "cancel" text. When I click the cancel text another error will appear in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Doing another pull of the SDK fixed the issue.